# Problem with equation

Tags: equations

[image]
I want to write this equation:

Here is my current LaTeX code:
  `D(u,v) = {(u-\frac{P}{2}^{2} + (v - \frac{Q}{2})^{2}]}^{\frac{1}{2}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\left` and `\right` give stretchy delimiters:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
 D(u,v) = \left[\left(u-\frac{P}{2}\right)^{2} +
               \left (v - \frac{Q}{2}\right)^{2}\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I learned something new, that would help a lot in future, thanks :)